# Type mismatch when dealing with list comprehensions

Tags: list, scala, list-comprehension

```
def combinations(list: List[(Char,Int)]): List[List[(Char,Int)]] = {
  list match {
   case List() => List()
   case x::xs => for(o <- List.range(0,x._2 + 1)) yield  List((x._1,o)) :: combinations(xs)
  }
}
```

This function won't compile properly as the comprehension will convert my result to a list resulting in a

```
List(List(List((Char,Int))))
```

The function is meant to find all the sub lists of a `List(Char,Int)` taking in consideration that `('a',2)` is a sub list of `('a',5)`

My question is can I somehow stop the comprehension making the end result a list? Am I missing the whole point of comprehension? Is this function even logically correct?

Comment: In what way is `(a,2)` a sublist of `(a,5)`? It's not a usual definition of sublist.

Comment: What is a `List(Char, Int)`? Lot of confusion between '()' and '[]' I think.

Answer (score 2):

`for` comprehension has a generator of type `List` so it yields a`List`. you are putting that `yield`ed `List` into another list.

Following compiles

```
def combinations(list: List[(Char, Int)]) : List[List[(Char, Int)]]= {
val t = List.range(0, 1)
list match {
  case List() => List()
  case (c,i) :: xs => val res = for {
    o <- List.range(0, i + 1)
  } yield (c, o)
  res:: combinations(xs)

 }
}
```

Comment: Yes it does compile but not as desired because the whole point of this algorithm is that it takes every element and it concatenates the combination of the tail which recursively should end up as having all the sub lists of a given list